# Is there any possibility to use the data which we got from Refcursor of procedure in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to display/use the data which I got from the refcursor from the out parameter of a procedure ( other than pipeline method)

Answer (score 1):

Not really, if you want to display the data in a standard Apex report format. 
As you've guessed, you'd have to create a pipeline function to loop through the cursor and return the records.

You don't say why you want to do this. Reasons I can think of include:

- to re-use existing code
- create a dynamic report design that changes automatically if you change the underlying refcursor

The first sounds reasonable to wrap your refcur in a pipeline function. But a dynamic result won't really work well in Apex.

We might be able to help more if you explained the overall goal for doing this.

Best of luck